# Yet another linking issue with unresolved symbols

Tags: c++, c, g++, arm

I am trying to build my program in OpenCL for ARM GPU - Mali.

I have a library libMali.so, which contains necessary symbols:

`arm-v7a15v4r3-linux-gnueabi-nm *root_to_lib*/libMali.so`

returns lines such as

`002525b4 t clCreateKernel`

and many others with all the expected OpenCL symbols.

However, compiling with

`arm-v7a15v4r3-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -Wall mandelbrot.cpp -o mandelbrot.o`

`arm-v7a15v4r3-linux-gnueabi-g++ mandelbrot.o -o mandelbrot -L*root_to_lib* -lMali`

gives me errors like

`mandelbrot.cpp:(.text+0x2e4): undefined reference to`clCreateKernel'`

and others with all the symbols, which are actually present in libMali.so!

So, I kept the correct order of librabies in linking command, library is on the specified path (it is indeed) and it has the symbols.
Mangling is not the issue in this case as well: `extern C` specifiers were used in place and you can see that the raw entries of both lib and object file are not mangled.
Trying to accomplish the same thing using the `arm-v7a15v4r3-linux-gnueabi-gcc` didn't bring any change apart from necessity to link more c++ libs by hand (with -L*path* -llib).
libMali.so was built with `arm-v7a15v4r3-linux-gnueabi-g++/gcc/ld`, so this is not the matter of toolchain version.

I've ran out of ideas. May be someone here knows more tricky parts of linking process?

**EDIT**:
In fact, `mandelbrot.cpp` is a sample code from Mali-SDK. I'm just showing my linker problem on this example, since there obviously are no problems in the code. You can see the code here:

http://malideveloper.arm.com/downloads/deved/tutorial/SDK/opencl/mandelbrot_8cpp_source.html

http://malideveloper.arm.com/downloads/deved/tutorial/SDK/opencl/mandelbrot_8cl_source.html

Comment: Could you post the actual code (perhaps a simple example that just does a basic kernel, and just enough for the clCreateKernel call). I do this all day, every day, so it's probably something simple, but without seeing the actual code that goes wrong, it's hard to say.

Comment: @MatsPetersson mandelbrot.cpp is the sample code from Mali-SDK. I didn't change a thing in it - I'm just testing the functionality for now. Compilation stage of the code is passed successfully, the only problem is linking - for some reason linker doesn't see the symbols.

Comment: Use `-Wl,--verbose`  (note: no spaces in the option) in your link command to tell the linker to dump info about libraries being searched just to make sure the tool is looking at the files you're expecting it to.

Comment: @MichaelBurr among other lines I can see `attempt to open *path_to_lib*/libMali.so succeeded`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely at the `nm` output:

```
002525b4 t clCreateKernel
```

you'll notice that the symbol is marked with a lowercase `'t'` which indicates that the symbol has a local binding (for example a static function) so it's not considered for binding to a undefined symbol in another object file.  You can find an explanation of most of the cryptic "symbol type" letters used by `nm` here: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/nm.html

The `readelf` utility's output is more clear about symbols types.

Maybe the library was built incorrectly?

Comment: Wow, you're right! I didn't actually know that lowercase `t` stands for local symbols, was only aware that it implies text/code section. And the output of `arm-v7a15v4r3-linux-gnueabi-readelf` gives lines like `106586: 002525b5    66 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   11 clCreateKernel`

Comment: @user3176112: so do you know why they are marked local? I'm not familiar with Mali (or OpenCL), but it looked like from the bit of stuff that popped up on Google that `clCreateKernel()` is intended to be called from user code.

Comment: No idea actually. But I will contact the developers who are actually building it from source. I guess it's just some stupid mistake on their side. Of course these symbols are supposed to be accessible, that's the whole point of having a library.